# Two switches do not work together in the mergefield field (\b and \@) for a date

Tags: microsoft-word, switch, mail-merge, field-codes

When I separately use the b switch or the @format switch on the mergefield field they work perfectly, but when I try to use them together the b modifier doesn't work.

In the images above the code is shown and below its value

[image]

[image: When the record is empty nothing appears with the text inside the field in the b switch.]

[image: The result with the other records is as expected]

Comment: Here is my go-to resource of mail merge: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. What it is it that you want to happen by using these switches? What is actually happening? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for answering:
I need to write the text "Fecha de firma: " inside the field so that when the record is empty nothing appears. if I wrote it off the field it would come out wrong. At the same time I need to change the date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are correct, they will not work together.*

### You will need two separate fields.

[image: screenshot]
The first field, with the two switches does not work, you are correct.

Below that are two fields in sequence with no space between.

```
{ IF { MergeField Fecha_de_firma }  > "" "Fecha de firma: "}{ Mergefield Fecha_de_firma \@ "MMMM d, yyyy" }
```

The thing is that the picture switch for the date cannot apply to the extra text. The first IF field substitutes for the \b switch.

(I use Word MVP Graham Mayor's [Add-In to Import and Export field constructions](http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm). It makes it easy to copy fields as text to and from forum posts.)

*Here is [my page on using Date Fields](http://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart) that explains the way to use the @ date picture switch. It works the same on Merge fields.*

Comment: Once again, thank you very much, Charles.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert it in the @ format in the same way as the other pieces of fixed text in there (e.g. `' de '` and `' del año '` ). e.g.

```
{ MERGEFIELD Fecha \@"'Fecha de firma: 'd' de 'MMMM' del año 'yyyy" }
```

(NB, it is OK in this case, but if you had a reallyy long piece of text it would not work as there are restrictions on the total amount of text a `\@` switch can generate - something like 64 characters).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please call off your attack bot.